# CouchDB view map function that doesn't segregate reduce keys

Tags: couchdb, mapreduce

Here is the doc *"schema"*:

```
{
    type: "offer",
    product: "xxx",
    price: "14",
    valid_from: [2012, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0]
}
```

There are a lot of such documents with many valid dates in the past and the future and a lot of times two or three offers in the same month. I can't find a way to make the following view: *Given a date, give me a list of the products and their running offer for that date.*

I think I need to emit the `valid_date` field in order to set the endkey of the query to the given date and then I need to reduce on the max of this field, which means i can't emit it.

Have I got it wrong? I am totally new to the map/reduce concept. Any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: why not u use timestamp for date field? and is pretty straight forward for range (startkey, and endkey)

Comment: Yes I could. I dont have strong opinion, i just though it would make it easier to manipulate it. But it doesnt change my problem I think.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really thrown by your comments about wanting to reduce, based on your requirements you want just a map function - no reduce.  Here's the map function based on what you asked for:

```
function(d) {
  if( d.type === 'offer' ) {
    var dd = d.valid_from;

    dd[1] = ( '0' + ( dd[1] + 1 )).slice(-2);   // remove the +1 if 7 is July not August
    dd[2] = ( '0' + dd[2] ).slice(-2);

    emit( dd.slice(0,3).join('-') );
  }
}
```

Then to show all offers valid for a given day you'd query this view with params like:

```
endkey="2012-08-01"&include_docs=true
```

Comment: So far so good, but now how can I get the running offer? The running offer is the doc with the max valid_from in a given range. Suppose for the sake of simplicity that I only keep the month number as valid_from. Suppose that I have 2 products and 3 offers for each one and I want to find the latest offer for each product in a specific month range. If I emit([month,product], offer) the map will be sorted by the month which means that I cant reduce by returning max(values.month). If I emit([product,month], offer) then I cant do range query on month.

Comment: Ok, that wasn't clear.  Just select the last row in what was returned.  If you have a lot of records, drop the `include_docs=true` from your query so you'll just get the ID from the last row, and then re-query for just that document.